# late +100 reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Recently i was given 100 rep to my ServerFault account for being associated with rest of StackExchange network. But, my account has been associated since the beginning. How did these points really come about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you link to an account with 200+ rep, you get the 100 rep bonus. I believe the bonuses were recently recalculated.

Comment: so i am guessing when i first made the Server Fault account, the feature to add +100 for the Stack Overflow account was not implemented yet. no such change in my Super User account so i must have gotten it on creation back then.